# How to show/hide a grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an application listing the events that occurred for any given day.
The application shows a DateTimePicker and the user selects a date. If there are events for that day, a grid shows up to list the found records.

If after that the user selects another date, i must destroy the previous grid in favor of the next one that may need to appear if event records are found for this newly selected date.

Doing the following isn't enough and i need to know what i am missing to get the desired behavior:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.destroy();
```

Comment: Please, do not create and destroy Grids. If the structure of the Grid is always the same, as it seems from the description of your problem, just change the filtering conditions in the datasource associated with the Grid. It is much faster, less memory consuming and mostly much easier to program.

Comment: So should i "destroy" it's internal datasource ?... How to do that... how to access the internal datasource ?

Comment: To access the dataSource you can do `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource` but again, no, please don't destroy anything just change the filtering condition or re-read the dataSource. How do you get the data from the server? Could you show your Grid and DataSource definition? Then I can show you how to do it with your code. Edit the original post for including it.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-destroy, that should remove all of the event handlers etc. from the grid.
After that, you just need to remove it from the DOM, i.e.

`$("#grid").remove();` http://jsfiddle.net/giltnerj0/JFy2C/

Comment: The grid will have to be redisplayed so i guess it would be better, as OnaBai mentionned, not to completely remove it from the DOM. I just want it to go invible mainly in case the newly selected date doesn't involve any "event" records for the database...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to destroy neither the Grid nor the DataSource. Instead, catch any change on the date and invoke a `DataSource.read`.

Steps:

- Define a DateTimePicker (or just a DatePicker or a Calendar) depending on your needs.

HTML:

```
<input id="date"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var evDate = $("#date").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value : new Date(),
    change: function () {
        ds.read();
    }
}).data("kendoDateTimePicker");
```

- Define a DataSource for retrieving events from the server. Lest assume that the `url` for processing the request is `GetEvents` that receives in the request an argument called `date` that is the the date for the events. Example `GetEvents?date=Mon+Jul+15+2013+19%3A44%3A55+GMT%2B0200+(CEST)`

JavaScript:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url : "GetEvents.php",
            data: function () {
                return { "date": evDate.value() }
            }
        }
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            id    : "id",
            fields: {
                event: { type: "string" },
                date : { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize : 10
});
```

- Define the Grid using previous DataSource:

JavaScript

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable  : false,
    pageable  : true,
    columns   : [
        { field: "id", width: 60, title: "#" },
        { field: "date", width: 140, title: "Date", format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}" },
        { field: "event", width: 400 }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

So the trick is defining a `change` event handler in the `DateTimePicker`: each time you change the date, it triggers a `change` event where you invoke a `grid.read()`.

The Grid `transport.read` defines as argument (`transport.read.data`) `date` plus the value read from `DateTimePicker`.

Comment: Thanks OnaBai ... but i probably made a mistake in the way i explained my situation... The application is already doing all that. I am fetching new data based on a new date... everything works... It's just that i need to know how to cleanly remove a grid so that it vanishes from the application window or to replace it with a new one with the new data based on this new date. So you say i just have to recreate a new grid with the same DOM element ?

Comment: No, I would say that you did not make any mistake. I understand that you already have some code what I cannot get why the _obsession_ about destroying the grid. Trust me, that will cause you problem and your application will be slower. Why is the `ds.read()` inside the `change` event of `DatePicker` not enough for you? That will refresh the grid with the events for the new date.